# How to animate fullscreen photo transition on swipe, like in Telegram?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

When you swipe vertically, image is dragged towards the swipe, with fading out animation of black background. 
And after release, it smoothly returns to it's previous position on the screen, like Hero animation does.

How is it possible to recreate such an effect using Flutter? The same scenario, in fullscreen photo view.
[photo_view](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view) package is desired for fullscreen, so it shouldn't interfere with zooming.

[image: Illustration of animation]

Comment: Dude, isn't Telegram open source?

Comment: @SeanBrookins It is. But it's not written on Flutter (which my question is related to -- please see tags).

Comment: I did see them, I was just going to suggest looking at their implementation :)

Comment: @SeanBrookins If only I knew where to look :D, I think it will take less time to think of this transition in terms of Flutter than to dive into their native code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. 
To create such an animation, you should use [extended_image](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_image) package, which has `SlideOutPage` widget for creation of such transitions.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is actually an out-of-the-box widget, and it's surprisingly easy to use. It's called `Hero`. Basically, you wrap the widget you want to animate like that in a `Hero` widget, with a specific `tag` string, and, when you navigate to another screen, you wrap the destination widget in another `Hero` with the same tag. An effect like the one you shared can be achieved by wrapping two widgets with the same photo with `Hero`es in different `PageRoute`s.

Check out this [Flutter widget of the week](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=Be9UH1kXFDw&feature=emb_logo) video to get you started, and [this Flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations) article for a more detailed explanation on `Hero` widgets.

Edit: I see you are looking for a more specific image-viewer behavior. Then, I suggest you use the [photo_view package](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view), which includes many functionalities to visualize images, including the hero transition with swipe-dow-to-dismiss behaviors, pinching to zoom, etc.

Comment: Problem here is not about Hero animation, but more about swipe handling. How would you use Hero to animate widget like this -- make it follow swipe, and come back on its place on previous screen when release finger?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Then, check out my edit in the answer.

Comment: That's exactly the package I am using. Can you please explain how to achieve animation simililar to gif in my question by using this package? I didn't found any swipe-down-to-dismiss parameters in this package.